# My batch file is executing multiple times

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Why is my batch file executing multiple times and opening several cmds?
It even crashed my Windows and I had to restart it.

This is the code inside it:

```
start cmd.exe /k "sass --watch main.sass:main.css"
```

If I place the code below, the same code runs multiple times inside 1 cmd

```
sass --watch main.sass:main.css
pause
```

Comment: What is the name of your batch file ??

Comment: You should in this case rename it other then sass.bat

Comment: @Hackoo, it worked.. I thought it would be fine lol, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just rename your batch file other then **sass.bat** and it will work !

Your problem is similair to this [Why does the ping command in my batch file execute in a loop](https://superuser.com/questions/298784/why-does-the-ping-command-in-my-batch-file-execute-in-a-loop)

keep this in your mind :

---

### **Don't name your bat files with the same name as existing programs.**